# Not show one validator in asp.net validationSummary

Tags: asp.net

I have several asp.net validators.
I want to show all(except one) error messages in validation summary.
How can I not show the remaining one in validation summary but in other places?

Answer (score 0):

Could you put the one you don't want to show in a different ValidationGroup to the rest?

Comment: This solution causes the validation not to occur.

Comment: Not necessarily, you can just use the overloaded Page.Validate method to validate any group you want, so you can quite easily validate multiple groups at once if you want to.

Comment: That is beside the point.  He still wants to validate the particular validator... he just doesn't want an error message in the validation summary.  Your solution is saying don't validate the validator.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood. If you have a separate ValidationGroup, you can still validate it (have a read up on the Page_ClientValidate method if you aren't aware of it) but the fact that it is in a different group will mean that it won't show up in the ValidationSummary. So, both groups get validated, yet the one in the other group doesn't show a message which satisfies the user's goal.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Text property of the validator to show in the validator itself.  The ErrorMessage property is what is displayed in the ValidationSummary

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basevalidator.errormessage.aspx